# how to post function data and variable data with ajax call

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to send my serialized sort data to my PHP script, but I need to add two other variables to the post request.
This is the code I am using, but I cannot seem to get the additional data added to the data attribute of the post.

the other two variables are plain strings. I have looked, but no matter what I try, it seems to screw up the serialized sort data.
I just need to send:

```
    var album 
    var ID
```

with the request, but can't seem to get the concantination right

```
$(function() {
        $('#refloader').hide();
        $( "#images" ).sortable({
                        stop:function(event, ui) {
                            $('#refloader').show();

                                $.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                url: "http://#######/sort.php",
                                                data:  $("#images").sortable("serialize", {attribute : "data-id"}),


                                                success : function(response)

                                                {
                                                    console.log (response)
                                                    $('#refloader').hide();
                                                    $("#ajaxresponse").append($(response));


                                                    }


                                              });
                                            }



        });

        $( "#images" ).disableSelection();
    });
```

when I use:

```
      data:  $("#images").sortable("serialize", {attribute : "data-id"}),
```

i get back :

```
         Array ( [0] => 2213132022 [1] => 2213131911 [2] => 2213130084 [3] => 2213130956 [4] => 2213129315 [5] => 2213128885 [6] => 2213129567
```

when i use:

```
   data:  { image : $("#images").sortable("serialize", {attribute : "data-id"}) },
```

I get back:

```
          image[]=2213129776&image[]=2213132022&image[]=2213131911&image[]=2213130084&image[]=2213130956&image[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this parameter to your ajax

```
type: "POST",
traditional: true,
```

you would normally wrap them all in an object

```
data:  { 
 images: $("#images").sortable("serialize", {attribute : "data-id"}),
 album: album,
 ID: ID
},
```

Comment: the code shown functions properly, I just do not know how to add the two variables at the top to the data set being sent .

Comment: hmmm, I tried that...but probably had the syntax wrong, i will give it a whirl...

Comment: @Jjames - It will also depend on how you collect it server side. You would need to have a single object with those parameters.

Comment: OK, that's where I am going wrong. Could you clue me in on how to collect that with PHP. I am using $items = $_POST['image']; which gets the serialized array properly, but not sure how to get thos out seperate from the other two variables

Comment: shouldn't it also follow that `$album = $_POST['album'];`?

Comment: thats what I was doing, I misunderstood, sorry.

Comment: it works until I wrap the jquery function into the data attribute.

Comment: I did have the syntax on the data object off at first though...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I got it licked, and figured I would post it for posterity.
The sortable function serializes to a string.
and that is what was changing in the function when assigned to variable.
So using the toArray method from the serialize function produced the proper result.

Thanks for the help.